# Mysql Check if user is already in the same group with other user

Tags: php, mysql

How can I check if the user X is in the same group as Y?

I'm making a chat application where I need to know if the user X is already opened a chat group with user Y. Because if so then do not create new group.

```
userId   | chatGroup
---------|---------------------
X        | bananas
Y        | bananas
3        | oranges
...
```

Like..

```
  $qry = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM chatUsers WHERE userId = :userIdFrom AND chatGroup = "bananas" AND userId = :userIdTo AND chatGroup = "bananas"');
  $qry->bindParam(':userIdFrom', $userIdFrom, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $qry->bindParam(':userIdTo', $userIdTo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $qry->execute();
```

Comment: I would recommend changing the column name since it can lead to confusion and many small bugs along the way of development. If you dont, simply put these around it: \`group\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name t1
INNER JOIN table_name t2
ON t1.chatGroup = t2.chatGroup
WHERE t1.userId = 'X'
AND t2.user_id = 'Y'
AND t1.chatGroup = 'bananas'
```

If you don't know the chat room name, then you can skip the last `WHERE` condition from the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a sub select:

```
SELECT 1 FROM chatUsers WHERE userID = :userIdFrom AND chatGroup = (SELECT chatGroup FROM chatUsers WHERE userID = :userIdTo)
```

The 2nd query will give you the group of the 2nd user. You then compare this group to your first user.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work.

```
SELECT
    IF(COUNT(*) > 0,
    'yes',
    'no') AS AreTheyInSameGroup
FROM
    chatUsers t1
WHERE
    userID = : userIdFrom AND chatGroup IN(
    SELECT
        chatGroup
    FROM
        chatUsers t2
    WHERE
        userID = : userIdTo
)
```

The idea is take from @infinitezero's answer. But I have used IN to search for group + added If for better clarification.